# How should a US expat in Europe file late taxes in USA?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a US citizen and permanent resident in Europe. I have filed US taxes while living in Europe in the past but I missed declaring my 2015 taxes.

I have used TurboTax "Deluxe" in the past. Is my best option to [buy the 2015 version](https://turbotax.intuit.com/personal-taxes/past-years-products/) or is there an easier/better option? Is there anything that I need to be aware of when filing late?

**NOTE**: FBAR is not an issue. That was done on time. It is only the tax declaration that is one year overdue.

Comment: Be sure you also file FBARs if you didn't already and had/have more than USD10k in financial _assets_ (not income) outside the US. Note this is [different than and separate from form 8938 in your tax return](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements), which I'd expect TurboTax can handle if it applies, although I don't have actual knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, but FBAR is not an issue, I am only asking about the tax declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you which software is your 'best option', but what you proposed would certainly work - as would several other softwares, or manually filling the paperwork, or using the free tools offered from some companies, if you don't have more complex requirements.

There is no special action needed when you file them (aside from showing the correct year on the filing); be aware that any due taxes you have to pay will get a late-fee and interest added to it. It is still a good idea to do it sooner than later; those fees and interests will just get worse if you wait.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the FBAR for 2017, the deadline was moved to April 15th starting this year, but there is an automatic 6 month extension to October 15 (please explain THAT one - I don't get it).  Anyway, you are not too late yet.

see here:  https://www.fincen.gov/news/news-releases/new-due-date-fbars-0

Comment: Thanks, but FBAR is not an issue, see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in your situation was to print out my prior and later year returns from Turbo Tax and used those as a guide to help me manually fill in the forms from the IRS.  My returns were substantially the same each year so the forms filled in by Turbo Tax guided me on which sections to fill in and how to fill them in.  I referred to the IRS documentation when I had questions or the forms had changed.  This was pretty painless and took me very little time.